# The quality of being "headstrong"

Tags: adjectives

I can think of two options for a word meaning "the quality of being headstrong":

- "headstrongness", which sounds horrid
- "headstrength", which feels like it could be more grammatically correct but sounds dumb

Which is correct? Tell me there's some hidden third option, but I have a sneaking suspicion it's "headstrongness" and that's upsetting.

Comment: There are many concepts that do not have words. Option 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider **wilfulness**.

> [**wilful**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/wilful?searchDictCode=all):
>   Having or showing a stubborn and determined intention to do as one wants, regardless of the consequences

You may also find [*determination*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/determination?searchDictCode=all) or some of its [synonyms](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english-thesaurus/determination) suitable, especially [*resolution*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/resolution#resolution__6) and [*resoluteness*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/resolute?q=resoluteness#resolute__4).

See these Ngrams for comparison: [**1**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wilfulness%2Cresoluteness%2Cheadstrongness&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwilfulness%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cresoluteness%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheadstrongness%3B%2Cc0), [**2**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wilfulness%2Cresoluteness%2Cheadstrongness%2C+determination%2C+resolution&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwilfulness%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cresoluteness%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cheadstrongness%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdetermination%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cresolution%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, I must confirm your suspicions - headstrongness is in fact the correct term, as defined in OED:

> The quality or state of being headstrong; wilfulness, obstinacy; waywardness.

Luckily, OED does offer three other suggestions - two have been given already by other users, but obstinacy is defined as

> The quality or condition of being obstinate; obduracy, stubbornness, inflexibility; persistency. Usu. with pejorative connotation.

More suggestions are presented in the definition above which you could investigate.